# Why does my number to buffer conversion cause the last byte to be set to zero?

Tags: javascript, buffer

As a project to study Assembly and x86-64 I'm simulating the registers in JS and the following code is giving me an unexpected result:

```
registers.rax.write(0x1f1f1f1f1f1f1f1f, 'unsigned');
console.log("updated rax", registers.rax.print());

registers.eax.write(0x1f1f1f1f, 'unsigned');
console.log("updated eax", registers.eax.print());

registers.ax.write(0x1f1f, 'unsigned');
console.log("updated ax", registers.ax.print());

registers.al.write(0x1f, 'unsigned');
console.log("updated al", registers.al.print());
```

Outputs the wrong value in the least significant byte position for only the 64 bit registers (at least it seems to be represented in Big Endian here to me, but I'm still wrapping my head around endianness).

```
printing DataView(8) {} : (8) [31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 0]
updated rax 1f 1f 1f 1f 1f 1f 1f 00

printing DataView(4) {} : (4) [31, 31, 31, 31]
updated eax 1f 1f 1f 1f

printing DataView(2) {} : (2) [31, 31]
updated ax 1f 1f

printing DataView(1) {} : [31]
updated al 1f
```

The code is as follows, what have I done wrong with my handling of 64 bit unsigned ints?

```js
const maxBigUint = 2n ** 64n - 1n;
const registers = {};
const registerContainers = {
  GPR: [],
  MMX: []
  // ...
};

for (let i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
  registerContainers.GPR.push(new ArrayBuffer(8));
}

function printHexStr(arr) {
  return Array.from(arr)
    .map((x) => {
      return x.toString(16).padStart(2, "0");
    })
    .join(" ");
}

class Register {
  constructor(name, buffer, offset, bits) {
    registers[name] = this;
    this.bits = bits;
    this.bytes = bits / 8;
    this.buffer = buffer;
    this.view = new DataView(this.buffer, offset, this.bytes);
    this.offset = offset;
    if (this.bytes == 1) {
      this.readMethods = {
        signed: "getUint8",
        unsigned: "getInt8",
        float: "getFloat8",
      };
      this.writeMethods = {
        signed: "setUint8",
        unsigned: "setInt8",
        float: "setFloat8",
      };
    }
    if (this.bytes == 2) {
      this.readMethods = {
        signed: "getUint16",
        unsigned: "getInt16",
        float: "getFloat16",
      };
      this.writeMethods = {
        signed: "setUint16",
        unsigned: "setInt16",
        float: "setFloat16",
      };
    }
    if (this.bytes == 4) {
      this.readMethods = {
        signed: "getUint32",
        unsigned: "getInt32",
        float: "getFloat32",
      };
      this.writeMethods = {
        signed: "setUint32",
        unsigned: "setInt32",
        float: "setFloat32",
      };
    }
    if (this.bytes == 8) {
      this.readMethods = {
        signed: "getUBigInt64",
        unsigned: "getBigUint64",
        float: "getFloat64",
      };
      this.writeMethods = {
        signed: "setUBigInt64",
        unsigned: "setBigUint64",
        float: "setFloat64",
      };
    }
  }
  print() {
    let arr = []
    for (let i = 0; i < this.bytes; i++) {
      arr.push(this.view.getUint8(i))
    }
    console.log('printing', this.view, ':', arr)
    return printHexStr(arr);
  }
  read(readMethod = "unsigned") {
    return this.view[this.readMethods[readMethod]](0);
  }
  write(value, writeMethod = "unsigned") {
    if (this.bytes === 8) value = BigInt(value)
    this.view[this.writeMethods[writeMethod]](0, value);
  }
}

// General Purpose Registers

new Register("rax", registerContainers.GPR[0], 0, 64); // Register A Extended
new Register("eax", registerContainers.GPR[0], 4, 32);
new Register("ax", registerContainers.GPR[0], 6, 16); // multiply/divide, string load & store
new Register("ah", registerContainers.GPR[0], 6, 8);
new Register("al", registerContainers.GPR[0], 7, 8);

new Register("rbx", registerContainers.GPR[1], 0, 64); // Register B Extended
new Register("ebx", registerContainers.GPR[1], 4, 32);
new Register("bx", registerContainers.GPR[1], 6, 16); // index register for MOVE
new Register("bh", registerContainers.GPR[1], 6, 8);
new Register("bl", registerContainers.GPR[1], 7, 8);

new Register("rcx", registerContainers.GPR[2], 0, 64); // Register C Extended
new Register("ecx", registerContainers.GPR[2], 4, 32);
new Register("cx", registerContainers.GPR[2], 6, 16); // count for string operations & shifts
new Register("ch", registerContainers.GPR[2], 6, 8);
new Register("cl", registerContainers.GPR[2], 7, 8);

new Register("rdx", registerContainers.GPR[3], 0, 64); // Register D Extended
new Register("edx", registerContainers.GPR[3], 4, 32);
new Register("dx", registerContainers.GPR[3], 6, 16); // port address for IN and OUT
new Register("dh", registerContainers.GPR[3], 6, 8);
new Register("dl", registerContainers.GPR[3], 7, 8);

// ## Pointer Registers

new Register("rsp", registerContainers.GPR[4], 0, 64);
// ... snip ...



console.log("registers", registers);

registers.rax.write(0x1f1f1f1f1f1f1f1f, 'unsigned');
console.log("updated rax", registers.rax.print());

registers.eax.write(0x1f1f1f1f, 'unsigned');
console.log("updated eax", registers.eax.print());

registers.ax.write(0x1f1f, 'unsigned');
console.log("updated ax", registers.ax.print());

registers.al.write(0x1f, 'unsigned');
console.log("updated al", registers.al.print());
```

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have 64-bit integers. Your input numbers are overflowing.

Comment: See the output of `console.log(0x1f1f1f1f1f1f1f1f.toString(16))` it also has the extra `00` byte.

Comment: @Barmar Ah right... How stupid, this was the whole point of using the BigInt conversion, but I forgot I can't just pass the 64 bit number to it before the conversion. I was too focused on being able to use Hex to set the bytes, which I'll instead have to do with an array rather than one number.

Comment: You can quote the 64-bit number, and BigInt will parse it.

Comment: @Barmar Ah nice, thanks!